# Detecting Overflow in Modulo Arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across the following checks for detecting overflow in unsigned integer arithmetic in a C program:
$$a+b < MAX\_UINT\implies\ a\lt MAX\_UINT-b$$
$$a*b < MAX\_UINT\implies\ a\lt MAX\_UINT/b$$
That seems however inefficient to me, because the operations $+$ and $*$ are performed in modulo arithmetic and it would be simpler to check
$$ a+b\gt \max(a,b)$$
$$ a*b\gt \max(a,b)$$
while the case of addition is easy to prove, I'm not sure about multiplication despite not finding counterexamples via computer search.

> Question:
>
> can the check for multiplication overflow be proven correct or are there counterexamples either for calculations $MOD\ 2^n$ or calculations for general $MOD\ n$?

Comment: A widely used detection for unsigned arithmetic is: If
$a+b < a$ then there was an overflow in addition (you can also test $a+b<b$).

Comment: Your multiplication test would falsely give overflow if
`a*a > a` and `1 < a < sqrt(MAX_UINT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have for instance $7^2 \mod 32 = 17$, and $10^2 \mod 64 = 36$. Generally for any power of two, you should expect lots of counterexamples. Note also that your formulas don't work for $a,b = 0$ or $a,b = 1$ (for the multiplication case).

However, you seem to have misunderstood the checks anyway; to see that you can safely perform $a + b$ in the unsigned integer type you are using, you have to check that $a < \mathrm{MAX\_UINT} - b$ holds; there is nothing modular about that.

Furthermore, there is usually nothing inefficient about the modular nature of addition and multiplication in a computer; that is just how those operations work in most ordinary instruction sets.